# Django DRF calculated fields check

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend, calculated-columns

I want to check if the computational values ​​coming from the frontend to the price table are correct.

E.g; The discount added to this by giving the Sales Price, the early booking discount is reduced to CostPrice. The difference between CostPRice and SalesPrice gives profiRate. The webFakePrice is calculated by calculating the salesPrice * webFakePriceRate for the price to be fake on the web. I want to check if these FrontEnd are calculated correctly. I could not find a keyword for it. How should I loop this since there are multiple record in one?

Model.py

```
salesPrice = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
costPrice = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
commissionRate = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
discountRate = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
earlyBookingRate = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
totalCommission = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
profitRate = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
webFakePriceRate = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
webFakePrice = models.FloatField (blank = True, null = True)
```

view.py

```
def create (self, request, * args, ** kwargs):
    many = True if isinstance (request.data, list) else False
    serializer = PriceSerializer (data = request.data, many = many)
    if serializer.is_valid ():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response (serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response (serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by checking in the Serializer.

Eg:

```
def age_restriction(dob):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - dob.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
    if (not(20 < age < 30)):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("You are no eligible for the job")
    return dob
class EligibilitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(validators=[age_restriction])
```

Source : https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/custom-validations-for-serializer-fields-django-rest-framework-44feabc1d06b